# Is it possible to access the parent node inside the loop?

Tags: loops, xquery, parent

I have a loop like this:

```
for $a in local:distinct-nodes($x/input/book[@stat = 'ok'])
let $b:=string($a/../input/@docid)
```

This returns an empty string($b is empty). So, I am wondering how I can access the parent node in this situation. I do not really want to access it from root (//xxxx) cause the XML file is quite large.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem you have and for a simple correction. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a loop like this:
>
> ```
>  for $a in local:distinct-nodes($x/input/book[@stat = 'ok']) 
>  let $b:=string($a/../input/@docid)
> ```
>
> This returns an empty string(`$b` is
>   empty).

Yes, this is what should be produced.

All $a nodes are `book` elements.

```
$a/..
```

are `input` elements

```
$a/../input
```

should be `input/input` elements, but most probably `input` elements dont have `input` children.

**What you want is**:

```
$a/../@docid
```

Comment: Dimitre, thanks for the answer. I can't get how I could miss that simple thing.